# How to test dropzone during dev

Tags: angular, cors, dropzone.js

I'm making an angular 5 app but independent of that I'm implementing dropzonejs (the angular wrapper) and since I'm not the back-end developper I don't have a handle on how the back is dev-ed.

right now CORS is refused on their end.

Am I to compile the entire bundled app, front and back, then run to be able to test each change I make like I'm doing right now or is there a better way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is.

You can rely on proxies to avoid CORS issues during dev.

Create a proxy file, `proxy.json`

```
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "http://your-url.com",
    "secure": false,
    "changeOrigin": true,
    "logLevel": "debug"
  }
}
```

Now, run this command.

```
ng serve --proxy-config proxy.json
```

All of your requests going to `http://your-url.com/api` will ignore CORS issues.

As a gentle reminder, if you use that, your HTTP calls should get rid of the url meaning this

```
this.http.get<any>('http://your-url.com/api/your-endpoint')
```

Becomes this

```
this.http.get<any>('/your-endpoint');
```

**[You can find more information here.](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md)**